# JavaScript: Bringing sequential order to force the execution of code AFTER Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

First i create an empty object, that should be updated by a certain array, whenever a button is clicked.

You can see this in *Step 1* and *Step 2*.

---

*Note that i used example code here. Its not intended to work*

**Step 1 : Creating the Object**

```
var obj = {};
```

**Step 2: Creating the Button**

```
Btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const a = [..];
    const b = [..];
    const c = [..];}

    obj['a']  = a;
    obj['b'] = b;
    obj['c']  = c;
);
```

**Step 3: Doing Sth with the UPDATED obj**

```
console.log(obj)
```

**Problem**

I used *console.log()* as an example, of course i want to do sth else with the code.

However, console.log() is executed before the EventListener. 
I understand why its that way, but how can I change this behaviour?

I have something, like the Promise-Technique with *.then()* in my mind.

Note, that i do **not** want to do this within the *addEventListener()** functionality, but outside of it!

Comment: Put what ever you want to do *within* the click handler, or call a function from there, and do your processing in that function (which may be defined outside of the event handler). Note that `then` still requires you to put logic within a callback function, which is what you already have available with your click handler.

Comment: What would you expect the value of `obj` to be *before* you click when you access it?    Or do you want to access the obj only after the click but not *during* the click event?  In which case have a flag `var obj = {}; obj.initialised=false;`  then when you want to use it `if (!obj.initialised) return` (and set to true in the click event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is clear that you cannot put your processing code at the top level of your script, since that executes immediately (and only once).

So you'll have to put the processing in a function. Since for some reason you don't want the click handler to be that function, define another one:

```
var obj = {};

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    obj.time = new Date;
    process();
);

function process() {
    console.log(obj);
}
```

You mention the use of promises and `then`. But `then` also requires a function (as its argument). But since you already have a callback function (the click handler), that doesn't really bring much of an advantage.

Another reason that a promise is not really suitable: a promise cannot resolve multiple times, so the callback you provide to its `then` method will never execute more than once. To really mimic the treatment of multiple clicks, you would have to create a new promise each time, or implement an observable. All this carries you only that far: in the end you will still be dealing with a callback function.

Comment: thank you very much! Especially for the explanation why a promise would be a bad idea.